# bottom-border + border-radius not working Galaxy S4

Tags: android, css, cordova

This is being made using phonegap/cordova and the emulators are from Genymotion.

I am trying to add a border to just the bottom, and then round the edges so I get a result like this:

[image]

As you can see, it works just fine on a Google Nexus 7 emulator. But when I try to run it on a generic android phone emulator, it ends up like this:

[image]

The relevant (no animation) css code for the the box is this:

```
width:90%;
height:39%;
margin:6% auto;
position:relative;
border-bottom:solid 20px black;
border-bottom-right-radius:50px;
border-bottom-left-radius:50px;
-moz-border-bottom-right-radius:50px;
-moz-border-bottom-left-radius:50px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:50px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:50px;
-ms-border-bottom-right-radius:50px;
-ms-border-bottom-left-radius:50px;
-khtml-border-bottom-right-radius:50px;
-khtml-border-bottom-left-radius:50px;
-moz-border-top-right-radius:50px;
-moz-border-top-left-radius:50px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius:50px;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius:50px;
-ms-border-top-right-radius:50px;
-ms-border-top-left-radius:50px;
-khtml-border-top-right-radius:50px;
-khtml-border-top-left-radius:50px;
font-size:6em;
text-align:center;
```

Answer (score 0):

As I remember -khtml is equal to -webkit (and -apple too), so you should use only -webkit vendor. -khtml is dedicated for konqueror - linux kde browser, and i think is useless on android device, -ms too.

Try change order of css declaration. Put declarations without verndors, pure border-bottom etc., at the end.

And if you can, test your code on live device.